# Get newsletter subscribers with API from Magento 2

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I'm setting up an integration between Magento 2 and Salesforce through the Magento API, all products, customers, orders and carts without problem, but I can't access newsletter subscribers through API.

I have tried to use the call
/rest/all/V1/subscribers but it gives me an error, that it does not exist.

Can somebody help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the customer API `{{magento_url}}index.php/rest/V1/customers/search?searchCriteria[pageSize]=100&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1`

that you seem to have already, will give you the subscribers
towards the end of the API response for each customer record, you can find the attribute: is_subscribed

Below is a snippet from a response on my local machine,

```
"disable_auto_group_change": 0,
            "extension_attributes": {
                "is_subscribed": false
            },
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "reward_update_notification",
                    "value": "0"
                }
            ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for de answer, but the problem is with the visitors, these visiting subscribers are not created in the customers table, however they are created in the subscribers table.